# Angular Lifecycle Hook Parameters

Tags: angular

Does Angular life-cycle hooks with the exception of `ngOnChanges` take any parameters? If so, in which ways can they be used?

Comment: You can test any parameters with `arguments` but AFAIK they don't accept any parameters besides ngOnChanges

Answer (score 3):

No, the other lifecycle hooks do not take parameters. Only `OnChanges`, which is why the docs have an example of `OnChanges`.

@see https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks